# Galactic and equatorial projected grids with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, astronomy

I'm attempting to draw a scatter plot of astronomic sources projected on a full sky map, using two coordinate grids: [galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system) and [equatorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system). Generating a single grid plot (using one of the pre-defined projections) is easy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random galactic coordinates
l_rad = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
b_rad = np.random.uniform(-np.pi / 2., np.pi / 2., 100)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(ra_rad, dec_rad, 'o', markersize=2, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I need though is a map with two grids superimposed: one for galactic coordinates (which is already there) and another one for equatorial. That is, a second grid like the one in the image below (notice the hour convention instead of decimal degrees for the right ascension) should be superimposed onto the first grid:

[image]

I think the [Kapteyn](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/) package can do [something similar](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/allsky.html#fig-34-hammer-aitoff-projection-ait-oblique) (image below) but I'd prefer to avoid it if possible (I find it rather complicated to use).

[image]

Comment: Obvious ugly last-resort workaround would be to plot with points (marker = '.') a gray "point cloud/point mesh" located on specified equatorial meridians/parallels and plot them after having converted their coords to galactic (?)

Comment: The package you link to seems to be based on matplotlib. So inside their sourcecode you will find the definition of that grid.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but I noticed Astropy.WCSAxes package has an example of drawing a map with overlaid galactic and equatorial grids: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/overlaying_coordinate_systems.html